# how to merge uicollectionview cell over tableview 1st cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, uitextfield, uitextview

I need to implement some functionality, A `collectionview` of 5-6 images,
each cell in `collectionview` is having a placeholder , each cell item is a photo picker or camera option

 at the bottom, I need tableview where i need to make inputs from user using text fields.

An example is like this..

[image: uploaded Sample]

Answer (score 0):

In your `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, simply set the first cell as a collectionview.

```
UICollectionView *myCollectionView = [UICollectionView new];
myCollectionView.delegate = self;
// Configure your collection view ...

if (indexPath.row == 0)
{
   return myCollectionView;
}
```

This code is not clean, it is just meant to give you a hint.

Comment: I got it.. I need to implement that picker in right form

Comment: I don't understand your question, what don't you manage to do ? The custom collection view cell with a button triggering uipicker ?